# There exists n such that number of primes between $(n+1)^{2021}$ and $n^{2021}$ is greater than 1122021140.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> To show there exists a natural number $n$ such that there are at least 1122021140 primes between $(n+1)^{2021}$ and $n^{2021}$.

Here is my attempt :

$\Rightarrow$
We define $\pi(x)=\#\{p \leq x \mid p$ is prime $\}$.

Then by prime number theoremn $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log x}$.

So I need to show $\pi(y)-\pi(x) > 1122021140$ for $y=(n+1)^{2021}$ and $x=n^{2021}$

For large $x$ we have (saw it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/288786/610697))
$$
\pi(y)-\pi(x) \sim \frac{y-x}{\log x} \tag1
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
&=\frac{(n+1)^{2021}-n^{2021}}{\log (n)^{2021}} \\
&=\frac{(n+1)^{2021}-n^{2021}}{2021 \log n}
\end{aligned}
$$

*I have two questions :*

1. How to prove equation $(1)$ i.e., $\pi(y)-\pi(x) \sim \frac{y-x}{\log x}$ for large $x$.
2. How to show there exists a $n$ such that $\frac{(n+1)^{2021}-n^{2021}}{2021 \log n} > 1122021140$.

Comment: 2 is easy as the numerator is $>2021n^{2020}$

Comment: You do not need 1). Just use the prime number theorem with good enough error term.

Comment: The equation (1) is at present just heuristics, and no proofs are known. It would imply for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_conjecture at least for $n$ large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon$, $M$ be positive numbers. Then there exists $n$ such that between $n^{1+\epsilon}$ and $(n+1)^{1+\epsilon}$ there are more than $M$ prime numbers. Indeed, otherwise a simple estimate would show that
$$\sum_{p \textrm{ prime}} \frac{1}{p} \le M \cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}< \infty$$
contradiction

$\bf{Added:}$ A similar argument shows that for every increasing sequence $a_n$ with $\sum \frac{1}{a_n} < \infty$ we have
$$\lim \sup_{n\to \infty} (\pi(a_{n+1}) -\pi(a_n)) = +\infty$$

Answer (score 3):

More directly, $n=1$ will work. There are many more than $1122021140$ primes between $1$ and $2^{2021}$, and we can prove it.

For example, there is a lower bound on $\pi(2n)$ via the prime factorization of $\binom{2n}{n}$ (for details, see [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1890792)) that tells us
$$
   \pi(2n)\ge \frac{n}{\log_2 (2n)}
$$
so in particular, $\pi(2^{2021}) \ge \frac{2^{2020}}{2021}$. This is much larger than $1122021140$: it's a number with over $600$ digits.

Answer (score 2):

From the question you link:

> There are unconditional results by Huxley and Heath-Brown showing $(1)$ for $h=y-x$ roughly being $x^{7/12}$.

Since $h\in O(n^{2020})=O(x^{2020/2021})=\omega(x^{7/12})$, there is an unconditional proof of $(1)$. Then $(2)$ follows by simply comparing growth rates of numerator and denominator.